# Azure Policy - Deny creation of new vnets if the new vnets CIDR exist already in any vnet rource in management group level

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-policy

I am trying to create an Azure Policy that denies the creation of new VNets if the CIDR of the new VNet matches any existing VNet resources at the management group level. This is to ensure that we do not have any overlapping IP addresses, which can cause issues with communication between resources.

I have looked into creating a custom policy, but I am not sure how to get the CIDR of the new VNet being created and compare it to the existing VNet resources at the management group level. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

```
"if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/addressSpace.addressPrefixes[*]",
            "notIn": "[subscription().virtualNetworks[*].addressSpace.addressPrefixes[*]]"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
"then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Policy - Deny creation of new vnets if the new vnets CIDR exist already in any vnet rource in management group level.

I have used the below **policy** below to restrict the creation of Venets if the **IP address** prefix matches.

```
{
"mode": "All",
"policyRule": {
"if": {
"allOf": [
{
"field": "type",
"equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
},
{
"anyOf": [
{
"field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/addressSpace.addressPrefixes[*]",
"contains": "[parameters('addressPrefix')]"
}
]
}
]
},
"then": {
"effect": "deny"
}
},
"parameters": {
"addressPrefix": {
"type": "String",
"metadata": {
"displayName": "addressPrefix",
"description": "The address prefix to check for"
}
}
}
}
```

If I try to create a **Vnet** with the same **IP address** prefix, the **policy** denies the creation of the **Vnet**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @VenkatV. I was hoping not to pass in any parameter, I want the policy to be able to check all existing address in the management group and deny it, really appreciate the help